# Java Graphics2D rotate painting

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I have a panel which is split into a number of sectors. I have attached a MouseListener to it. Each drag event generates a point, adds it to the ArrayList and calls repaint. As the mouse is dragged the mouse pattern is drawn in every sector by Looping trough the ArrayList and calling the Graphics2D rotate method. If I drag the mouse slowly I can see the points incrementally being painted on the screen. How can I fix that?

```
//performs the drawing on the display panel
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);


    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;    
    g2d.setColor(penColor);

    this.sectorLine = new Line2D.Double(getCenterX(), getCenterY(), getCenterX(), 0);
    g2d.setClip( new Ellipse2D.Double(getCenterX() - getLineLength(), getCenterY() - getLineLength(), getLineLength()*2, getLineLength()*2));


    //draws the sectors on the screen
    if(drawSectors)
    {   
        drawSectorLines(g2d);
    }   


    for (Point point : points)
    {   
        g2d.fillOval((int) point.getX() -4 , (int) point.getY() -4,8, 8);       // has to return the size of the pen /2 methog get offset
                                                                                // dva metoda za sektori i rotate
        rotate(g2d,getNumberOfSectors() - 1);


    }   


}

//rotates each drawn point in every sector
public void rotate(Graphics2D g2d, int times)
{
    g2d.setColor(penColor);

    for(int i=0; i<times; i++)
    {                             // returns 360/number of sectors
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(getRotationDegrees()), getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
    }
}


// handles drawing
private class DisplayListener extends MouseAdapter
{   
    private void addPoint(MouseEvent event) 
    {
        Point point = event.getPoint();
        points.add(point);
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
    {
        addPoint(event);

    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
    {
        addPoint(event);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the rotate method?

Comment: This must have become popular as homework. Must have seen 4 variants of this same question in last 48 hours!

Comment: Well i am trying my best to do this coursework on my own but i do not have the necessary knowledge.

Comment: 1) Tip: Add @MauricePerry (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). (Same advice I gave on most of the variants of this question.) 3) Don't let 'trying to do it on my own' stop you from asking us for help ..or looking at any of the other questions relating to the same thing.